# Good web based download manager?

Tags: php, web-applications, download

I'm looking for a good web based "download manager" open source application. Mainly a web based interface to some files in a Linux server filesystem. I've looked in sourceforge and google can't find a good one. Maybe I'm searching it with the wrong keywords?

PHP is preferred, but can be written in other programming languages as well.

Some features I'm looking for:

- Capability of users and groups of users, with login and password;
- Upload and delete files in filesystem from the web based interface;
- Set permission in uploaded files or in group of files based in users or group of users;
- Listing of files;
- Relatively easy to adapt templates;

Thanks!

Comment: This Q might have a better chance of gettiong good answers at ServerFault, where most server geeks are hanging around.

Comment: Alex is right, unless you want to write it yourself.

Comment: I've thought about it, but since "Easy to adapt templates" is a must in my opinion (involves html/css editing), I thought SO was appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any solutions that could provide what I described. We are going to implement this solution in-house.

Thanks for all your responses. "Reinvent the wheel" is the way to go when all the wheels you got just don't fit in your car.

Comment: Can you Open Source it ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole bunch of such scripts on [hotscripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/file-management/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for, as I need same and I don't want to reinvent wheel.

FATRAT: http://fatrat.dolezel.info/