# What are the uses for Joomla?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, design-decisions

I've taken over development for a site that was started to be built in Joomla.  So far, there is just a few static pages and user registration.  The specs state it will basically be a file-sharing website.  The admin's (and only admin's) will add files and the user's will be able to download some of those files from the Members Area (based on the current date).

From my limited experience with Joomla in the past few hours it seems to me that Joomla is good for having a semi-static website where non-technical admin's can add/edit content but it doesn't seem good for being able to add customized dynamic content (I haven't been able to figure out yet how I can add a new page where I can access the database).

I am thinking to propose the current Joomla site be scratched and start over with a PHP framework instead so it can be customized.  Is my understanding of Joomla correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review your requirements. If what you described here is really all you need, you don't need a CMS, you need some kind of download manager. Joomla is useful, but not in your case (apparently, it's up to you to decide).

IMHO, you're using wrong tools to acomplish your goals. Using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter, Zend Framework or others to implement only user registration/groups and files associated to these users is the way to go. It's easier than try to search through all Joomla extensions, read through all Joomla extension documentation and such. In the end, being so desperate of "I may not reivent the wheel" you may create complex extensions when sometimes all was needed were a bunch of php files. You spent days and days "searching for ways of implementing in Joomla" when you could have done exactly what you needed from scratch in the same amount of time.

Don't be afraid of "reinventing the wheel". I've asked a question about a [download manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446624/good-web-based-download-manager) here in SO too and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. The solution: develop my own.

Comment: Decided to follow this and use CodeIgniter.  The learning curve was too high for me with Joomla for such a small project with a quick turnaround needed.

Answer (score 2):

For File download [Phoca Download][1] a very capable File Download Manager for Joomla.
Another one that is pretty good would be [Remository](http://remository.com/).

[1]: http://www.phoca.cz/phocadownload/ Phoca Download

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to drop Joomla over a php framework because Joomla is php based and you can write custom modules for your own use.  In fact, there are a large number of modules/extensions and other resources that can be added to the default installation to create a more customized environment.

I would suggest looking at [Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/) and [Extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/) pages to see if any of the functionality you need is already included and can be added to your Joomla deployment.  Plus, if you need to create a customized feature that is not available through Joomla or Joomla developers you can always create your own functionality by writing your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is probably the most popular PHP CMS.

The real question is, what are you going to do next?

If you do not know the answer, then it is worth using Joomla on the chance that a Joomla module will do what you want.

If you use straight PHP, then you will be stuck coding from scratch.

-FT

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what what is meant by new page in your case. Joomla has plenty of extensions which also include tools for front end content adding. It's true that PHP framework will mean constant coding to add something new or improve anything, while Joomla and its extensions are simple to add/remove and enable /disable. If this is so necessary you can code something new for Joomla.

Just think more deeply what it is gonna be you develop now.